# Apache - Deny access to all directories except public

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am developing a tool and I'm stuck at this point: I want to define a set of rules for each directory, basically I want only 'Public' folder avaible, and to deny access to other folders.

My directoy structure is

```
uapi(root)/
    Application
    Config
    Public/
         Index.php
    Storage
    .htaccess
```

and here is .htaccess file

```
<Directory /Public>
    Order Deny, Allow
    Allow from all
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ Index.php/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory /Config>
    Order Deny, Allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory /Application>
    Order Deny, Allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory /Storage>
    Order Deny, Allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Maybe try removing/commenting out the `Rewrite...` directives, if it'll work the problem is there.

Comment: I looked in access.log and its kepps saying <Directory not allowed here

Comment: generally speaking if you have control of the server and are not on shared hosting, putting this stuff in the server config (httpd.conf) is better / faster as apache doesn't need to look for and parse .htaccess files on each request.  If you are shared hosting you are stuck with the .htaccess method (in most cases)

Comment: Why not a single .htaccess file in the root "Deny from all"
And a .htaccess file in /Public folder with "Allow from all"
The .htaccess file in the /Public folder should overwrite the .htaccess file in the root?
That would avoid to have a .htaccess file in each folder /Application, /Config, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As this [doc page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory) says, you cannot use the `<Directory>` directive inside htaccess, but only inside server conf files.

This is not a problem in your case anyway: you can store one `.htaccess` file inside each directory, eg. create these files:

**Public/.htaccess**

```
Order Deny, Allow
Allow from all
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ Index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**/Config/.htaccess**

```
Order Deny, Allow
Deny from all
```

**/Application/.htaccess**

```
Order Deny, Allow
Deny from all
```

**/Storage/.htaccess**

```
Order Deny, Allow
Deny from all
```

Comment: I know that but is there any way to all this from one file

Comment: Yes, you could put all the directives you wrote inside a virtualhost config, or the main Apache config file. See also: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#virtualhost .

Answer (score 2):

You can do all that using mod_rewrite itself from your main `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file. Use this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(Application|Storage)(/.*|)$ - [NC,F]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^Public/(.*)$ /Public/Index.php/$1 [L,NC]
```

This code will throw *Forbidden* error for all the requests for `/Storage/*` or `/Application/*` but will let `/Public/*` be handled by `/Public/index.php`.

Answer (score 1):

For **Apache httpd server 2.4** you can do that in this way:

In httpd.conf or in a .conf file in httpd/conf.d/ dir.

```
<Directory "/uapi/">
  Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory "/uapi/public">
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I tested this config. The reference is [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#run-time).

You should be able to do this in .htaccess files too, if you don't have access to the Apache config files.
That would be, in /uapi/.htaccess:

```
Require all denied
```

and in /uapi/Public/.htaccess

```
Require all granted
```

As mentioned above, you can't use  inside an .htaccess file. From [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#files):

> `Note that unlike <Directory> and <Location> sections, <Files> sections can be used inside .htaccess files.`

More general documentation:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html